# How does one correctly translate the Weight Watcher PointPlus formulas to code?

Tags: php, ruby, math

Looking for the correct way to code the Weight Watcher PointsPlus formulas for "Food Values" and "Food with Alcohol and Sugar Alcohol" into Ruby and/or PHP.

Here is the link to the formula: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weight_Watchers#Formulas

Thanks in advance for the help!

Update:

As per the help from @mjayt below, I have the code below. My goal is to learn how to properly think, organize and solve formulas through code. I believe help correctly solving the two formulas will greatly help. Thanks again.

```
$protein = 8;
$carbs = 30;
$fat = 12;
$fiber = 8;
$pointsplus = round((($protein * 16) + ($carbs * 19) + ($fat * 45) - ($fiber * 14)) / 175, 0);
echo $pointsplus;
```

Comment: If you can add in what code you have presently, that will give answerers something to advise you upon.

Comment: That link give a very thorough explanation of how to do so... it's just math. Break it down into its components and pay attention to order of operations in code and you should be fine. Unless you're just trying to get someone to do the heavy lifting for you?

Comment: @halfer - I have no code at the moment.

Comment: @mjayt - I'm a below average coder with forgotten math skills. Was looking to learn from the answers posted here.

Comment: See below... I did the first one. The second is almost the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I was bored... here is the first one. This should get you going

```
$protein = 8;
$carbs = 30;
$fat = 12;
$fiber = 8;
$pointsplus = round((($protein * 16) + ($carbs * 19) + ($fat * 45) - ($fiber * 14)) / 175, 0);
echo $pointsplus;
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know enough math to know this but the formula is preceeded by max { round(...),0 }. Is "max" something that needs to be calculated or not? Pardon my lack of math knowledge here.

Comment: I don't think so... it has been a while for me on the math classes as well, but I found another online calc and plugged the values in and they both returned 6 points so I don't think anything else is needed at least for this one.

Comment: Really appreciate the help @mjayt. The max was the part that was confusing me... still want to know exactly what it is but this helps. Thanks.